# PTIJ: Looking for audio resources

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I know that some commentators made [emendations](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/commentaries-on-the-talmud/) or provided explanations to Talmudic text, and that some of these can be listened to on dedicated online radio stations. I have found one for the Haga'ot Ha[Bach](https://www.classicalradio.com/bach), and there is one through which one can hear the work of the [GRA](http://www.wgra.net/) and even a [Rashi](https://www.facebook.com/Rashi-radio-1515117885197088/) Radio, but am still looking for one dedicated to the work of Tosafot.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The link for the Gra is dead.

Comment: @DonielF mistyped. Fixed. TY

Comment: (long live the link for the Gra!)

Answer (score 7):

It's right here - Extra Radio.

https://soundcloud.com/extra-radio

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re interested in any other Mefarshim, may I recommend the [(Maha)RShA](https://www.radio.net/s/rsa), the [ROSh](http://www.liveonlineradio.net/ireland/ros-fm.htm), and the [RIF](http://radioriff.com/web/)?